# MongoDB/PHP: Stuck with a complex query

Tags: php, mongodb

I'm performing the following MongoDB query in PHP:

```
$driver_coords=$mongo->eamorr->driver_coords2;
$time=time();

$query=array("loc"=>array('$near'=>array($lat,$lng)),array("timestamp"=>array('$gt'=>$time-60)));
$drivers=$driver_coords->find($query);   //this keeps returning null!
```

on the following collection:

```
{
   "_id": ObjectId("4ff5f9e0d27faa0132000016"),
   "loc": {
     "lat": 53.399998333333,
     "lng": -6.2599983333333
  },
   "niceTime": "2012-07-22T16: 43: 55+01: 00",
   "timestamp": NumberInt(1342971835),
   "uname": "Eamorr"
}
```

Now, if I set `$query=array("loc"=>array('$near'=>array($lat,$lng)))` (i.e. remove the second part); it works just fine. I cannot get the query to work on the timestamp part.

Could someone please let me know what I'm doing wrong?

Many thanks in advance,

Comment: also, what happens when you remove the $near part and just query based on timestamp? Do you get back the records you expect?

Comment: When I query based just on timestamp, it returns the correct results...

Comment: I tried this: `$query=array(array("timestamp"=>array('$gt'=>$time-60)),array("loc"=>array('$near'=>array($lat,$lng))));` but still can't get it to work... ;(

Comment: @AsyaKamsky got it! `$query=array("timestamp"=>array('$gt'=>($time-60) ),"loc"=>array('$near'=>array($lat,$lng)));` Thanks for your help,